# how to parse the details in the struct before dequeue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

I have initially pushed a pkt into a queue. I wish parse the details in the pkt before dequeue. How can I get this information. Thanks or your help.

```
struct pkt{
    int data;
    int time;
};


void start_gen (int input_port_num)
{
pkt mypkt;

 mypkt.data = 5;
 mypkt.time = 10; 


 per_port_pkt_queue[input_port_num].push(mypkt);

}

void parse_info ()
{


//Try to dequeue

struct decoded_data;

decoded_pkt=per_port_pkt_queue[1].pop();
std::cout<< "The packet was taken from"<< decoded_data.date << "has the data" << decoded_pkt.time << time;

}
```

Comment: You can use `per_port_pkt_queue[1].front()` to get it without poping.

Comment: I actually want to look at the contents of the pkt. Kind of peek into the pkt and if my condition matches, I wish to pop it.

Comment: can't you split the different types of packets into different queues in the first place? This way all "consumers" will needlessly peek / parse most item until it reaches one that it can handle. IOW, make a routing facility that does the routing, instead "blind" consumers that do duplicate work all the time

Comment: How is `per_port_pkt_queue` declared?

Comment: @milleniumbug inb4 `std::vector<boost::circular_buffer<pkt> >` - I've seen his previous q

Comment: Acutally I have started to use std::vector<std::queue<pkt>> per_port_pkt_queue curretly. In my future version I may move to boost

Comment: Thanks all. I found the issue. It was a silly mistake. I had to create decoded_data of type pkt. But I just declared it as struct.